# CSS styling methodology: From inside to outside or vice versa

Tags: css

When I have to style a webpage is it better to begin from the outer most element and continue towards the inside or the other way around, from inside to outside?

For example giving

```
<div class=outer>
    <div class=inner>
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    width: 170px;
    ...
    ...
}

.inner {
    height: 170px;
    ...
    ...
}
```

what is wiser? Style first the outer class and add more specific directives to inner class or vice versa?

I apologize if this is a too general question, but I always end up to do it randomly without any proper order, so I was curious to see if there are some suggestions and/or guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always style from outside in. It allows me to build a tructure and layout first, and then move on to the details from there.

Comment: +1 I always did it this way & have always seen it done this way.

Comment: Yep also add there is some inheritance of properties like `font size or color or family ...`  That can improve your code lines.. Improve your answer to get more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I consider that the most important thing is to write your stylesheets grouping things logically, so that it is easy to find things both while still writing it, and months later when you have forgotton what you did.

I write all the stuff that applies globally to all pages first, and within that I put the rules for the header first, then the ones for the middle section, and finally the footer's rules. After that I put the rules for individual pages, keeping all stuff for a single page together. That way I always know where to look for what I want (but I include a few comments in /*...*/ as well, eg one before each page to say which page it is).

What you do has little effect on the outcome on screen if you give all selectors enough specificity. The order only matters if you want to overide one rule by something coming later, and use the order they are in to decide which one wins, but I consider that bad practice, as it all falls over if you later move things around within the sheet and inadvertantly move something that depends on order.